# Double integral with two dx

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I don't know how to solve this double integral:

$$\iint_E {y\over x^2+y^2} \ dx\, dx$$

where $E = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : y \in [1,2], x \ge 0, x^2+(y-1)^2 \le 1 \}$.

Appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: Most likely there was a typo and it should have been $dx dy$ or $dy dx$ (basically, $dA$).

Comment: Is it resolvable with two dx? Cause my professor usually conceives unusual exercises

Comment: No $dxdx$ really doesn't make sense over the two dimensional domain like that.

Comment: @albicocco, maybe i should rephrase. It is a typo. with 2 dx's it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

By switching to polar coordinates, then setting $t=2\arctan u$,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{r^2+r\sin t}{r^2+2r\sin t+1}\,dt\,dr = \int_{0}^{1} r\arctan\frac{1}{r}\,dr $$
then by using integration by parts:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} r\arctan\frac{1}{r}\,dr = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{r^2}{r^2+1}\,dr\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
That also follows from $\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}=-\frac{d}{dx}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ and [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't get what you did once you switched to polar coordinates

Comment: @albicocco: I used Weierstrass substitution.